# Limit git log based on number of lines inserted/deleted?

Tags: git

I don't see any obvious way of doing it, but git has proved time and again to be way more flexible than I assumed, so...

I want to find commits which introduced large code changes, so I'd like to limit them by number of lines inserted or deleted (either together or separately). Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 3):

`git log --stat`

```
commit e2b97c53727bd66c143713d13399ff4242e4ff06
Author: John Hobbs 
Date:   Thu Nov 4 17:01:14 2010 -0500
    Switched to jQuery Mobile. It's awesome.
 application/classes/controller/item.php    |   77 +++++++++++++---------------
 application/classes/controller/project.php |    4 +-
 application/classes/controller/site.php    |    2 +
 application/classes/controller/user.php    |    5 +-
 application/classes/form.php               |    2 +-
 application/views/item/add.php             |   27 +++-------
 application/views/item/index.php           |   19 ++-----
 application/views/item/view.php            |   11 +++--
 application/views/message/basic.php        |   13 +++++
 application/views/mobile.php               |   64 ++++++++++++++++++-----
 application/views/project/add.php          |    5 +--
 application/views/project/index.php        |   28 ++++------
 application/views/project/view.php         |   19 ++-----
 application/views/user/index.php           |   25 +--------
 application/views/user/login.php           |   14 +++--
 application/views/user/register.php        |   20 ++++---
 16 files changed, 165 insertions(+), 170 deletions(-)
```

(sample output from [here](http://www.velvetcache.org/2010/11/24/git-log-stat))

Then visually look for long +/- signs or use `--numstat` and pipe it to another command to filter it.

`man git log`

---

If you need to filter it instead doing it visually (`--shortstat` as recommended by Antoine):

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --shortstat
```

This will give you output like this:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --shortstat
19791900f886e7a5f92b7cf3536053c863bec067 fix tab title, system menu, and a focus
 2 files changed, 108 insertions(+), 65 deletions(-)
b52941150046cdb455c38e3f9bc133d6ba8f721f give tab a wndproc, change time to be
 1 files changed, 65 insertions(+), 20 deletions(-)
ae5c18524b4a02b264fe26319ce2c9cf7dbff6b2 Fix window style of parent window
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
8f94ad9bbbb2fec42feccda43374b13eda55c018 Add .gitignore to ignore some MSVC file
 1 files changed, 10 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Pipe that to awk, searching for 'files changed, ', and printing the matching line and previous line if the number of insertions is greater than 50:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --shortstat | awk '/files changed, / && $4 > 50 {print x; print};{x=$0}'

19791900f886e7a5f92b7cf3536053c863bec067 fix tab title, system menu, and a focus
 2 files changed, 108 insertions(+), 65 deletions(-)
b52941150046cdb455c38e3f9bc133d6ba8f721f give tab a wndproc, change timer
 1 files changed, 65 insertions(+), 20 deletions(-)
```

Source for some of the awk arguments: http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/05/print-currentnextprevious-line-using.html

Comment: If that was the actual answer, I would recommend `--shortstat` instead

Comment: I knew that. Now, do you have an answer to the question that was actually made?

Comment: I didn't know you knew how to do that.  Additionally, if I were looking for commits with large changes, I would probably want to do a manual filter, visually, so I wouldn't miss any commits.  If you filter out all commits with less than 50 lines changed, you'll miss a commit with 49 changes that might interest you.  Anyways, I edited my answer to filter using awk.